# C++ segmentation fault on input

Tags: c++

I am getting a segmentation fault error after inserting an input file in this program I can't find where is the problem, could anyone help me with this?(it's the solution for the USACO training milk2 question).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <limits>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   std::ifstream in ("milk2.in");
   std::ofstream out ("milk2.out");
   std::vector< pair <int,int> > v;
   int n,i,maxn,maxs,t,ts;

   in >> n;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
     in >> v[i].first >> v[i].second;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
     if (v[i].second<(v[i+1].first)
     {
      t=v[i+1].first-v[i].second;
      if (t>maxn){
        maxn=t;
      }

     }
    else
    {
      ts=v[i+1].second-v[i].first;
      if (ts>maxs)
      {
        maxs=ts;
      }
    }
   }
   out << maxs <<" "<< maxn;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The faulting line would help...

Answer (score 4):

When you create the vector `v`, it's *empty*. So any index, even zero, will be illegal.

You need to first create the entries in the vector, e.g. by doing [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).